# Direct sum and linear independence

Tags: linear-algebra, direct-sum

By the definition, if $W$ is a vector space and $U_1,U_2$ are the subspaces of $W$ then the direct sum $W=U_1 \oplus U_2$ holds iff the following is true: $W=U_1+U_2$ and every vector in $W$ has a unique representation as a sum of a vector from $U_1$ and a vector from $U_2$.

However, I read [here](http://algebra.math.ust.hk/vector_space/13_direct_sum/lecture2.shtml) that "by the definition, the condition for a sum to be direct is
$\mathbf{u_1}+\mathbf{u_2}=\mathbf{0},~~ \mathbf{u_1} \in U_1, ~\mathbf{u_2} \in U_2$"

and I fail to understand why is that true. The definition says that $\mathbf{u_1}+\mathbf{u_2} \in W$, but why $\mathbf{u_1}+\mathbf{u_2}$ is necessarily equal to the zero element? What is the point then of the direct sum if every sum of two vectors from two subspaces is zero?

Comment: As far as I can understand, the condition is:$$u_1+u_2=0\implies u_1=u_2=0, \, u_1 \in U_1, u_2 \in U_2$$

Comment: @thanasissdr - i missed that. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's suppose $W=U_1\oplus U_2$ in the sense you have defined in your first paragraph.

Note that
$$
\underbrace{0}_{\in W}=\underbrace{0}_{\in U_1}+\underbrace{0}_{\in U_2}
$$
so by the uniqueness of the representation on the RHS above, **if** you have
$$
\underbrace{0}_{\in W}=\underbrace{u_1}_{\in U_1}+\underbrace{u_2}_{\in U_2}
$$
then $u_1=0$ and $u_2=0$.